# Calico node cannot build with server's ip address

Tags: kubernetes, calico

When I add the k8s work node to the master control-plane, the pod of calico-node report a error show that the server's ip connection is unhealthy.

```
Warning  Unhealthy  36s   kubelet, izbp1a13o0oyyyt66ldcdhsj  
Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with XX.XX.XX.XX 
2020-02-03 08:16:54.740 [INFO][119] health.go 156: Number of node(s) with BGP peering established = 0
```

I using kubeadm to create the cluster, the master node seems work ready. This error show when I join other work node, it looks like the calico net framework not work correctly between them.

The `kubectl get nodes` show the two node are all ready.

The `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` show there are two calico-node pod in the namespace kube-system, and they are all report error show above.

Comment: https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2901

Answer (score 1):

Refer this on official [calico troubleshooting guide](https://docs.projectcalico.org/maintenance/troubleshooting)

```
Error: calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with x.x.x.x
```

Top three cause are as below try eliminate them

> 1 : This “unready” status error in Kubernetes means that a **particular peer is unreachable in the cluster**. Check that BGP connectivity between the two peers is allowed in the environment.
>
> 2: This error can also **occur if inactive Node resources are configured for node-to-node mesh**. To fix this, decommission the stale nodes.
>
> 3: This error can also **occur when BGP connections to non-mesh peers go down**. If this is a common occurrence in your BGP topology, you can disable BIRD readiness checks. See node readiness for more information.

Comment: Sorry, could show me how to check the BGP connectivity between the two peers, I can not access to the official web site.

Comment: depends on your router type .. say if juniper you can refer [this link](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/verification/bgp-peers-process-summary.html)

Answer (score -2):

solution
We modify the calico-node container of calico.yaml and add the IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD environment variable:

```
containers:
- name: calico-node
  image: docker.io/calico/node:v3.18.1
  ...
  env:
    # This is the environment variable we need to add

    - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
      value: "interface=eth.*"
```